# Convert delegate to lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

My coding standards plugin is complaining and telling me to use a lambda for this delegate but the only suggested fix is to ignore the warning, how do I go about this?

```
myobb.Populate += delegate(string s1, string s2)
{
    string s3 = s1 + s2;
    SomeObject.DoSomething(s3);
};
```

Comment: You are not using the `s3` variable you declared. The anonymous function does nothing currently.

Comment: This was a shorthand example of what I'm actually trying to do, the inner workings of the delegate work fine as it stands, I just want to convert it to a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
myobb.Populate += (string s1, string s2) =>
{

};
```

or simpler:

```
myobb.Populate += (s1, s2) =>
{

};
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, that's all I needed :)